# Binding Lists of Commits to a DataGridView in Winforms with an MVP architecture

Tags: c#, winforms, rubberduck, databinding

I'm using Winforms and I find this pattern showing up in my code a lot. It works, but I'm unsure if it's *best*. The goal is to pass an `IList` of items through a view interface and then bind that list to a DataGridView in the concrete GUI class. I've been accomplishing this by keeping a private `BindingList<T>` in the control, and converting the `IList` when getting/setting the properties. I can't help but feel that there's a better way to do this databinding.

The GUI looks like this.

[image: Control with Fetch, Push, Pull, Sync buttons and two empty DataViewGrids]

The View interface.

```
public interface IUnSyncedCommitsView
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Fetch;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Pull;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Push;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Sync;

    IList<ICommit> IncomingCommits { get; set; }
    IList<ICommit> OutgoingCommits { get; set; } 
}
```

The UserControl code behind.

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public partial class UnSyncedCommitsControl : UserControl, IUnSyncedCommitsView
{
    public UnSyncedCommitsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetText();
    }

    private void SetText()
    {
        CurrentBranchLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.SourceControl_CurrentBranchLabel;
        FetchIncomingCommitsButton.Text = RubberduckUI.SourceControl_FetchCommitsLabel;
        PullButton.Text = RubberduckUI.SourceControl_PullCommitsLabel;
        PushButton.Text = RubberduckUI.SourceControl_PushCommitsLabel;
        SyncButton.Text = RubberduckUI.SourceControl_SyncCommitsLabel;

        IncomingCommitsBox.Text = RubberduckUI.SourceControl_IncomingCommits;
        OutgoingCommitsBox.Text = RubberduckUI.SourceControl_OutgoingCommits;
    }

    private BindingList<ICommit> _incomingCommits;
    public IList<ICommit> IncomingCommits
    {
        get { return _incomingCommits; }
        set
        {
           _incomingCommits = new BindingList<ICommit>(value);
            this.IncomingCommitsGrid.DataSource = _incomingCommits;
        }
    }

    private BindingList<ICommit> _outgoingCommits;
    public IList<ICommit> OutgoingCommits
    {
        get { return _outgoingCommits; }
        set
        {
            _outgoingCommits = new BindingList<ICommit>(value);
            this.OutgoingCommitsGrid.DataSource = _outgoingCommits;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Fetch;
    private void FetchIncomingCommitsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = Fetch;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Pull;
    private void PullButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = Pull;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Push;
    private void PushButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = Push;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Sync;
    private void SyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = Sync;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the pattern in particular that I'm *really* worried about.

> ```
>     private BindingList<ICommit> _incomingCommits;
>     public IList<ICommit> IncomingCommits
>     {
>         get { return _incomingCommits; }
>         set
>         {
>            _incomingCommits = new BindingList<ICommit>(value);
>             this.IncomingCommitsGrid.DataSource = _incomingCommits;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: What exactly is your "worry" ?

Comment: I don't know @janos. Last year I just fussed with this until it worked. I didn't really know what I was doing at the time and now I just blindly follow this pattern because it works. I guess I'm concerned that I made a rookie mistake and never bothered to find out if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem I see here is that the current approach will generate deeply nested `BindingList` objects if you repeatedly call the setter with a list you previously got from the getter. If you see what I mean. Probably you don't really do such thing in practice, but it's still ugly.

I'm going to assume that you generally want the getter return the same list that was originally passed to the setter. That is, if you passed some list `x` to the setter, you want that list `x` back from the getter, not some `wrapped(x)` list.

To make this work, you would need to keep the original list, or have a way to access it again if the setter puts it in a wrapper.
It seems this can be done using a `BindingSource`:

- Create a `BindingSource` with a `BindingList` and `null` parameter, and keep it in a field
- Bind your grid to this `BindingSource`
- Make the list getter return the underlying list with `bindingSource.List`
- Make the list setter replace the underlying list, either by replacing the list in the `BindingList`, or by replacing the `BindingList` in the `BindingSource`

This last item is a [work in progress](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22432607#22432607).
I spent some time searching through the docs for it,
but it seems harder than I expected.
(Btw I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform/16695971#16695971) illuminating.)

If all else fails, you could clear the underlying list and add all elements from the incoming list.
Depending on how you use the getters and setters,
you might want to do some defensive copies as appropriate.

Unrelated to your main concern, the code duplication when calling the fetch/push/... handlers is not great, with the boilerplate null checks. It would be good to create a helper method `CallHandlerIfNotNull` or similar.

Comment: Linq provides the `ToList` method, but that's it. I do see what you mean though. Thanks. As for the duplication in event handlers, I've been told before that this was the recommended pattern... I'll do some research on that. Can't remember why that was at the moment.

Comment: I'll be very surprised if you can find a recommendation that beats down such helper method. About `ToList`, it would be good to find out if it will copy the list content or return the underlying list itself. If it's not clear from the docs, you could do a test with code: extract the underlying list with `ToList`, modify it, and see if the underlying list was modified too

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. That could be good or bad depending on my use case, but I need to find that out regardless.

Comment: [ToList *does* create a new list... of the same objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2774121/1188513)

Answer (score 3):

Abstractions are useful only so far as they remain *useful*. Once you start jumping through hoops to maintain an abstraction, you should reflect on whether it's still useful. By choosing to rely on an `IList<T>` instead of a `BindingList<T>`, you've lost the benefits of using a binding list, while jumping through hoops to "make it work". You're also breaking a number of [Microsoft's Guidelines for Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx) in the process.

> **X DO NOT** use `ArrayList` or `List<T>` in public APIs.
>
> These types are data structures designed to be used in internal implementation, not in
>   public APIs. `List<T>` is optimized for performance and power at the
>   cost of cleanness of the APIs and flexibility. For example, if you
>   return `List<T>`, you will not ever be able to receive notifications
>   when client code modifies the collection. Also, List exposes many
>   members, such as BinarySearch, that are not useful or applicable in
>   many scenarios. The following two sections describe types
>   (abstractions) designed specifically for use in public APIs.
>
> **✓ DO** use `Collection<T>` or a subclass of `Collection<T>` for properties or return values representing read/write collections.

Now, the view interface is your public API and `BindingList<T>` subclasses `Collection<T>`, so it's completely appropriate to expose the binding list directly and have your Presenter/Controller modify the View's collections directly.

```
public interface IUnSyncedCommitsView
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Fetch;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Pull;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Push;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Sync;

    BindingList<ICommit> IncomingCommits { get; }
    BindingList<ICommit> OutgoingCommits { get; } 
}

public partial class UnSyncedCommitsControl : UserControl, IUnSyncedCommitsView
{
    private readonly BindingList<ICommit> _incomingCommits = new BindingList<ICommit>();
    public BindingList<ICommit> IncomingCommits {get {return _incomingCommits;}}

    private readonly BindingList<ICommit> _outgoingCommits = new BindingList<ICommit>();
    public BindingList<ICommit> OutgoingCommits {get {return _outgoingCommits; }}

    public UnSyncedCommitsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetText();
        this.IncomingCommitsGrid.DataSource = _incomingCommits;
        this.OutgoingCommitsGrid.DataSource = _outgoingCommits;
    }

    //...
}
```

You'll notice that I removed the setters from both the interface and implementation. From the [same document as before](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ***X DO NOT*** provide settable collection properties.
>
> Users can replace the contents of the collection by clearing the collection first and then
>   adding the new contents. If replacing the whole collection is a common
>   scenario, consider providing the AddRange method on the collection.

We've lost the `List<T>` abstraction, but gained a ton of usability/maintainability by getting on the *right level* of abstraction and encapsulating the view's data. If we want to modify the view's data, we need to go through the view to do it. The best part, is that the framework handles the databinding and UI updating for us. Win.

What's not so nice about this, is that `BindingList<T>` is very much a WinForms thing. We couldn't create a WPF or some sort of web view that uses the same Presenter class, so maybe this isn't quite the *right* level of abstraction. You know what though? *That's probably okay*. There are two types of coupling: Physical and Logical. No matter what we do to physically decouple the View from the Presenter, they will still be *logically* tightly coupled. If the view changes, the presenter will likely need to change too. That's just how it is. Being that Rubberduck is an add-in for a desktop application, it's unlikely you'll ever create a web based view of this logic anyway.

That said, if you're really concerned about leaky abstractions and the ability to easily move to WPF, you can define the lists of things in your interface to be `Collection<T>`s. Both [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) inherit from `Collection<T>`, so defining your interface to return a collection, and backing it in your implementation with a binding list works perfectly well.

```
public interface IUnSyncedCommitsView
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Fetch;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Pull;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Push;
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Sync;

    Collection<ICommit> IncomingCommits { get; }
    Collection<ICommit> OutgoingCommits { get; } 
}

public partial class UnSyncedCommitsControl : UserControl, IUnSyncedCommitsView
{
    private readonly BindingList<ICommit> _incomingCommits = new BindingList<ICommit>();
    public Collection<ICommit> IncomingCommits {get {return _incomingCommits;}}

    private readonly BindingList<ICommit> _outgoingCommits = new BindingList<ICommit>();
    public Collection<ICommit> OutgoingCommits {get {return _outgoingCommits; }}

    public UnSyncedCommitsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetText();
        this.IncomingCommitsGrid.DataSource = _incomingCommits;
        this.OutgoingCommitsGrid.DataSource = _outgoingCommits;
    }

    //...
}
```

So, finally, we have the right level of abstraction, while letting the framework take care of all the nitty gritty details of binding the data to the UI.

Comment: Since you removed the setters, you could keep using `IList<T>`.  The guideline warning about exposing list types speaks to using the concrete `List<T>` class rather than `IList<T>`.